# Linq: Method has no supported translation to SQL - but how to dump to memory?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Linq query that reads from a SQL table and 1 of the fields it returns are from a custom function (in C#).

Something like:

```
var q = from my in MyTable
        select new
        {
           ID = my.ID,
           Amount = GetAmount(ID)
        };
```

If I do a `q.Dump()` in LinqPad, it shows the results, which tells me that it runs the custom function without trying to send it to SQL.

Now I want to union this to another query, with:

```
var q1 = (from p in AnotherQuery.Union(q)...
```

and the I get the error that `Method has no supported translation to SQL`.

So, my logic tells me that I need to dump q in memory and then try to union to that.  I've tried doing that with `ToList()` and creating a secondary query that populates itself from the List, but that leads to a long list of different errors.  Am I on the right track, by trying to get q in memory and union on that, or are there better ways of doing this?

Comment: did you configure linkPad to your sql? with EF ?

Comment: No specific EF configuration - just added a connection to SQL and ran LinqPad as a c# program.

Comment: in order to run link against your DB you need to load you EF configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use any custom functions in a LINQ query that gets translated - only the functions supported by the given LINQ provider. If you want your query to happen on the server, you need to stick with the supported functions (even if it sometimes means having to inline code that would otherwise be reused).

The difference between your two queries boils down to when (and where) the projection happens. In your first case, the data from `MyTable` is returned from the DB - in your sample, just the ID. Then, the projection happens on top of this - the `GetAmount` method is called in your application for each of `ID`.

On the other hand, there's no such way for this to happen in your second query, since you're not using `GetAmount` in the final projection.

You either need to replace the custom function with inlined query the provider understands, or refactor all your queries to use the supported functions in addition with whatever you need to do in-memory. There's no point in giving you any sample code, since it depends entirely on your *actual* query, and what you're really trying to query for.

Comment: Thanks. I agree that without giving exact code you will not be able to provide an exact answer.  But to ToList() everything and then to Union on that does seem to work the best.  Thanks.

Comment: @CameronCastillo It might work best if you have very little data. If you expect the data returned by the `ToList`s to grow big, you'll have to redo everything anyway.